# Using Microsoft Azure Face API Person Groups

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using Azure Face API for the first time and I am following their documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244)

to build a proctoring system. I have managed to create students and add their faces to the API and then trained the model. To achieve that, I have created one FaceGroup called Students and inside the group I have created individual students then added their faces.

Now my question is whether I should create a PersonGroup for each student or just create generic PersonGroups e.g.Students' and then create Persons inside the group as individual Students.

My main concern is that as of now I have a person Group called Students under which I have created individual students as persons, then added their faces and every time I add a person to that group i have to retrain the whole model with all the persons in it. Should it be like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One PersonGroup is as one training dataset. You should only create one PersonGroup for your scenario and use PersonGroup Person - Create to add persons(your student) into the group, finally call PersonGroup - Train to get the **whole group** ready for Face - Identify.

A person group is a container holding the uploaded person data, including face recognition features. Your training will train the whole set so that you do not need to train every time after you adding your student.

-Yutong